# PowerPoint doesn't remove chart titles

Tags: vba, charts, title, powerpoint

I've written this code but the code fails to remove the chart titles when it is run. If I run the code manually using the step-in function it works perfectly. 
I've tried using `Application.Wait` before the `newChart.HasTitle = False` line but it doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

```
Sub InsertPieCharts()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim aTB As Table
Dim aSL As Slide
Dim sh As Shape
Dim newChart As Chart
Dim aTX As Shape
Dim chartAreasWidth As Double, chartAreasHeight As Double, firstLeft As Double, chartsHSpace As Double, chartsLeft As Double, chartsTop As Double, firstTop As Double, chartsVSpace As Double, tHeight As Double, tWidth As Double, cWidth As Double, cHeight As Double
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

'Measures
chartAreasWidth = 25 'cm
chartAreasHeight = 4.4 'cm
firstLeft = 3.13 'cm
firstTop = 13.01 'cm
tHeight = 1 'cm
tWidth = 1 'cm
cWidth = 2.5 'cm
cHeight = 2.2 'cm

'Objects
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set aSL = ActivePresentation.Slides(16)

For Each sh In aSL.Shapes
    If sh.HasTable Then
        If sh.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange = "Datatable" Then
            Set aTB = sh.Table
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next sh

chartsHSpace = xl.CentimetersToPoints(chartAreasWidth / (aTB.Columns.Count - 1))
chartsVSpace = xl.CentimetersToPoints(chartAreasHeight / (aTB.Rows.Count - 2))
chartsLeft = xl.CentimetersToPoints(firstLeft)
chartsTop = xl.CentimetersToPoints(firstTop)
tHeight = xl.CentimetersToPoints(tHeight)
tWidth = xl.CentimetersToPoints(tWidth)
cHeight = xl.CentimetersToPoints(cHeight)
cWidth = xl.CentimetersToPoints(cWidth)


For r = 3 To aTB.Rows.Count
    For c = 2 To aTB.Columns.Count
        Set newChart = aSL.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlPie, chartsLeft - (cWidth - tWidth) / 2 + cWidth * (c - 2), chartsTop - (cHeight - tHeight) / 2 + cHeight * (r - 3), cWidth, cHeight).Chart
        With newChart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1)
            .Cells(1, 2).Value = ""
            .Cells(2, 1).Value = "Fill"
            .Cells(2, 2).Value = aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange * 1
            .Cells(3, 2).Value = 100 - aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange
            .Cells(3, 1).Value = "Unfill"
            .Rows(4).Delete
            .Rows(4).Delete
        End With

        newChart.ChartData.Workbook.Close

        If newChart.HasTitle = True Then
            newChart.HasTitle = False
        End If
        If newChart.HasLegend = True Then
            newChart.HasLegend = False
        End If

        newChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(176, 176, 176)
        newChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Format.Fill.Visible = False




        Set aTX = aSL.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, chartsLeft + chartsHSpace * (c - 2), chartsTop + chartsVSpace * (r - 3), tWidth, tHeight)
        aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange = aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange
        aTX.TextFrame2.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
        aTX.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        aTX.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval

        If aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange > 89.5 Then
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            aTX.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(47, 105, 151)
        ElseIf aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange > 79.5 Then
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            aTX.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(169, 202, 228)
        ElseIf aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange > 69.5 Then
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            aTX.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 170, 170)
        ElseIf aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange >= 0 Then
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            aTX.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If

        If aTB.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange > 99.5 Then
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
        Else
            aTX.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
        End If

        aTX.Width = tWidth
        aTX.Height = tHeight

    Next c
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my own problem seems to first force the chart titles and then removing them like this

```
newChart.HasTitle = True
newChart.HasTitle = False
```

instead of

```
If newChart.HasTitle = True Then
        newChart.HasTitle = False
End If
```